# vapor toolbox broken after upgrading swift

Tags: swift, vapor

Vapor toolbox is crashing when trying to use it after upgrading to Swift 3.1.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __TTSfq4n_s___TFVSS13CharacterView38_measureExtendedGraphemeClusterForwardfT4fromVVSS17UnicodeScalarView5Index_Si
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vapor
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __TTSfq4n_s___TFVSS13CharacterView38_measureExtendedGraphemeClusterForwardfT4fromVVSS17UnicodeScalarView5Index_Si
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vapor
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Swift ABI is not yet stable. Thus, Swift programs (like Vapor Toolbox) must be recompiled to work with new versions of the language.

### Reinstall with Brew

Simply re-installing the toolbox should fix this issue.

```
brew reinstall vapor/tap/vapor
```

### Replace Old Installation With Brew

You may need to delete the existing executable if you did not originally install with Homebrew

```
rm /usr/local/bin/vapor
```

Then ensure the executable is gone

```
which vapor
```

You can now install with brew

```
brew install vapor/tap/vapor
```

Comment: In my case, re-installing toolbox got stuck after linking ./.debug ... I had to delete the executable and then re-install

Comment: Good catch, I added some more information about this.

Comment: I love you, @tanner0101 :D

Comment: If it's not already linked, you will need to run `brew link vapor`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply delete Vapor executable from

```
/usr/local/bin
```

And then run the toolbox install script from the documentation

```
curl -sL toolbox.vapor.sh | bash
```

Comment: I'd recommend installing with Homebrew. It's easier to be notified when updates are available.

Comment: With the `brew install vapor/tap/toolbox`, I was getting `Error: No available formula with the name "vapor/tap/toolbox" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: The formula is called `vapor/tap/vapor` now.