# Vapor doesn't work with xcode 9 and swift 4

Tags: swift4, xcode9, vapor

When I try to compiled my newly created vapor project with Xcode 9 I get 189 compile errors.  What's the trick to making this work?  I installed vapor and the toolbox, and create via 'vapor new test --template=api' and then 'vapor xcode' to start it up.

Comment: Some examples that have been migrated to Vapor 2 + Swift4 are posted on github [Vapor Examples Lab](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Xcode 12 / Swift 5.3 Update**

`vapor` is now part of `homebrew/core`. Source: github [homebrew-core/Formula/vapor.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vapor.rb).

```sh
##### If applicable, remove the obsolete 'vapor/tap' #####
## List current taps:
brew tap
# homebrew/core
# vapor/tap
## Remove tap:
brew untap vapor/tap

#### Install current version of vapor #####
brew install vapor
brew upgrade vapor
```

**Xcode 9 / Swift 4**

Check that everything is up to date. The following builds and runs for me at this time:

***Use latest vapor toolbox.***

Currently:

```sh
vapor new test --template=api
cd test
swift package tools-version
# 4.0.0
# use `swift package tools-version --set-current` if needed
rm Package.resolved
vapor update
vapor --version
# Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.2
# Vapor Framework: 2.3.0
```

Note, `Vapor Framework:__` only shows when the terminal working directory `pwd` is pointing to a vapor project directory.

If needed ...

```sh
brew tap --full  vapor/homebrew-tap
brew update 
brew upgrade
```

In some cases the vapor toolbox may need to be deleted and reinstalled. (*see ["vapor toolbox broken after upgrading swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071458/vapor-toolbox-broken-after-upgrading-swift)*)

***Use latest Xcode release.***

Currently: Xcode: 9.1, Swift: 4.0.2

```sh
swift --version
# Apple Swift version 4.0.2 (swiftlang-900.0.69.2 clang-900.0.38)
```

***Use `vapor update` or `swift package update`***

```sh
vapor new test --template=api
cd test
rm Package.resolved
vapor update
```

alternately,

```sh
vapor new test --template=api
cd test
rm Package.resolved
swift package update
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

The above updates, compiles and runs OK for me in Xcode 9.1.

Note: However, there are about 44 new deprecation warnings of the same type. I first became aware of the `characters` deprecation with Xcode9.1/Swift4.0.2.

> 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly"

So, new deprecation warnings, but 0 errors ... and, more importantly, the project runs as Vapor 2 + Swift 4.

Also, check `Packages.resolved` versions versus what is available in each respective source repository. On github, the Vapor Examples Lab: [TemplateApiTest](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab/TemplateApiTest) repository contains the `Packages.resolved` which was generated and works with the tool chain scenario above.

**Finally, double check that the target is `Run` on macOS and not an ARM-based iOS for this build.**

[image: Xcode schema Run > My Mac]

Comment: I have the same toolbox version, but mine version command doesn't show the framework output.  My swift version is the same as yours (note you said vapor instead of swift in that command copy).  I still get 193 errors.

Comment: `swift package tools-version` retuns an error that there's no such file or directory package.

Comment: OK, everything looks the same as yours.  My tools-version says 4.0.0.  But I get tons of xcode errors when I open the project

Comment: Here's an example from Crypto, which is failing.  My openssl came from brew.  ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib

Answer (score 1):

Try 'brew upgrade vapor', if using brew. If you're using apt, try "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install vapor". This worked for me. I think because I had installed 2.0 a while ago, which couldn't sink with 3.0 projects.